# Constant 60KB Shared library memory on /proc/<pid>/maps

Tags: linux, process, memory, proc, shared-library

In a quest for understanding RAM requirements of system processes, I arrived to analysis of `/proc/pid/maps`.

I have noticed a pattern: many shared libraries have exactly 60KB space allocated in their virtual memory right after the code, with permissions `---p`, meaning non-executable, non-writable, non-readable and private.

My guess is that it is not the .text .data or .bss sections of the shared library because it is not r/w/x.

What is it? can it be reduced?

When using `/proc/pid/smaps` to further dive in,  I haven't seen it in RSS (Resident Memory), so one can claim that it is of no importance to RAM use.

I tried to relate it to the executable or shared library sections by using objdump or readlef, but I could not find a section that's 60KB.

For example:

```
76d2d000-76d94000 r-xp 00000000 1f:00 439        /lib/libc.so.0
76d94000-76da3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0     (What's that?)
76da3000-76da4000 r--p 00066000 1f:00 439        /lib/libc.so.0
76da4000-76da5000 rw-p 00067000 1f:00 439        /lib/libc.so.0
76da5000-76dab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Comment: This might be better suited on superuser.com I think. No massive Linux experience here, but personal guess would be some "no-man's-land" to isolate code or possibly some side-effect of address space randomization?

Comment: Could be some [red zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_%28computing%29)